# How to start Gulp watch task when I type npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, package.json

I have a gulp.js file that includes:

```
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Which starts up the watch task

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(productionScripts, ['autoConcat']);
});
```

Then on any saved changes to files in productionScripts, the watch task will concat the files.

What I would like to do, is in my package.json, I would like to spool up this watch when I type npm start (this already starts my node server).

package.json

```
    "start": "node server.js",
```

**UPDATE**--------

Ben(b3nj4m.com), I tried what you stated. The watch and server start up. However, everything runs twice (probably due to the editor, not related), but I do lose my server log when I start it up with gulp.

```
[15:31:18] Starting 'autoConcat'...
[15:31:18] Finished 'autoConcat' after 147 ms
[15:31:19] Starting 'autoConcat'...
[15:31:19] Finished 'autoConcat' after 138 ms
[15:31:20] Starting 'autoConcat'...
[15:31:20] Finished 'autoConcat' after 127 ms
[15:31:23] Starting 'autoConcat'...
```

It's like there is a loop between the server restarting on a change, and the concatenated file changing.

Comment: use `gulp watch` instead and tie starting and restarting your server into the gulp watch process, that way when you change code for your server, gulp will restart it.

Comment: instead of npm start you recommend gulp "myFunctionName" with the server starting in gulp? Do you have an example?

Comment: I do not, i just know that it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could run your server from your gulpfile:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('default', ['server', 'watch']);

gulp.task('server', function() {
  var server = child.spawn('node', ['server.js']);
  var log = fs.createWriteStream('server.log', {flags: 'a'});
  server.stdout.pipe(log);
  server.stderr.pipe(log);
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(productionScripts, ['autoConcat']);
});
```

Then change your `npm start` definition to look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "gulp"
}
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to get the server log back would you?

Comment: `child_process.spawn()` returns a `ChildProcess` object, which has `stdout`, and `stderr` streams. You can pipe those streams somewhere, e.g. to a file. I will add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You could concatenate multiple tasks in your `start` in `package.json` using the package `concurrently` as such:

```
{
  "start": "concurrent \"node server.js\" \"gulp\" "
}
```

And run `npm start` from your terminal. This would execute all statements within `start`.

For references: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by @Josh in the comments, the CLI name now matches the package name. Hence, you could write the script as:

```
{
   "start": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"gulp\" "
}
```

Comment: Should not it be `concurrently` and not `concurrent`?

Comment: The package name is `concurrently`. The command used to execute the package is `concurrent`.

Comment: @nashcheez I did but on npm start the scss is not getting compiled to css as it should be. Here is the code in package.json:                                               "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"gulp\" ",

Comment: @angular2 I am guessing there is an error with your gulp file code (for conversion of scss to css) rather than the command here.

Comment: @nashcheez This is no longer the case. The CLI name now matches the package name, ie `concurrently`. https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently/releases/tag/2.0.0

Comment: `"start": "concurrently 'node server.js' 'gulp'"`

Answer (score 7):

I have something like this in one of my projects. Note that it will background both processes - you can use `ps` to get the ID and stop it with `kill <pid>`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "{ gulp watch & node server.js & }"
}
```

To disable logging, too:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "{ gulp watch --silent & node server.js & }"
}
```

Comment: What's the second & for?

Comment: Without it the command will fail with an `ELIFECYCLE` error; you need to background both tasks in the one command.

Answer (score 6):

One best practice to consider is to use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) and then like the accepted answer, trigger the gulp script from npm with `npm start`.  It's blazing fast and you get the node server restarted on file changes.  For example:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

...

var nodemonOptions = {
    script: 'bin/www.js',
    ext: 'js',
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' },
    verbose: false,
    ignore: [],
    watch: ['bin/*', 'routes/*', 'app.js']
};

gulp.task('start', function () {
    nodemon(nodemonOptions)
        .on('restart', function () {
            console.log('restarted!')
        });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    ...

    "scripts": {
        "start": "gulp start"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.0",
        "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```