# Node.js package start file not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I have my package.json file like this:

```
{
  "name": "chat_app",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "The second iteration of the chat app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "index.js"
  },
  "author": "Tino",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
var app = require('express')(),
express = require('express'),
http = require('http').Server(app),
jade = require('gulp-jade');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
})
```

When I type: `node start` it does not work. Why is this? Much help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: package json should read "start" : "node index"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scripts in your package.json should read:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js"
},
```

To run these scripts use the commands

`npm test`

or

`npm start`

Using npm scripts gives you the flexibility to chain commands and use build tools.

[You can read more about this here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

**Example**

Install nodemon, a tool that automatically restarts your node application when you make changes.

> Just use nodemon instead of node to run your code, and now your process will automatically restart when your code changes.
>   ...from your terminal run: `npm install -g nodemon`

Now in your package.json add the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js"
},
```

And from your command line run this command:

`npm run dev`

This should give you a basic understanding of how npm scripts work.

[The docs for nodemon are here if you are interested.](http://nodemon.io/)

Comment: Thanks for showing nodemon, it looks very useful! Would I be able to start gulp and node at the same time by saying `"dev": "nodemon index.js gulp"? Or do I need to write something else, thanks!

Comment: If you have a look here you should find a pattern that works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029929/how-to-start-gulp-watch-task-when-i-type-npm-start

Comment: I realized also that I can run two terminal windows at the same time and thus run different tasks at once on different terminals. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

the scripts simply run the command you write in them in the shell/terminal. so if you want to run `npm start` and have node running `index.js` you need to write

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```